# Should another answer be designated as the accepted one for this Python-related question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

The question is [“Is there a way to clear the value of a variable in python?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237647/clear-variable-in-python/52463466), and the accepted answer is to assign to that variable a value of `None`.

However, [assigning to a variable a value of None and deleting that variable don’t seem to be functionally identical.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473185/what-is-a-none-value) And even if giving the variable an empty value was the goal, wouldn't `self.left = ''` (or something else) still be a more accurate solution than `self.left = None`?

Two possible arguments for why `self.left = None` shouldn't be considered the accepted answer for this question:

```
>>> a = "a"
>>> b = "b"
>>> c = "c"
>>> d = ['foo', 'bar', 'choco', 'Kiki', 'Buba']
>>> #Argument N1
>>> a = ""
>>> del b
>>> c = None
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>> a
''
>>> type(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
>>> type(c)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> c
>>>
>>> #Argument N2
>>> d[1] = a
>>> d
['foo', '', 'choco', 'Kiki', 'Buba']
>>> d = ['foo', 'bar', 'choco', 'Kiki', 'Buba']
>>> d[1] = b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
>>> d
['foo', 'bar', 'choco', 'Kiki', 'Buba']
>>> d[1] = c
>>> d
['foo', None, 'choco', 'Kiki', 'Buba']
```

Answer (score 10):

The acceptance mark is set by the user asking the question, and it is completely up to them to choose which answer they accept. It just means that it is the answer that helped them the most - it does not mean it is a helpful answer for everybody or even a correct answer.

So, no, we can't and shouldn't change the accepted answer. You can comment on it instead, and you can (and should) downvote incorrect answers and upvote correct answers.

See ["What does it mean when an answer is accepted?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in the help section.